# rails on heroku : webpack dev_server configuration not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a rails project deployed to heroku. After deployment, the CSS packaged by webpack does not work, but it works normally local.
Famous in Heroku's Application Logs:
webpack dev_server configuration not found in /app/config/webpacker.yml[production]
Please run bundle exec rails webpacker:install Webpacker
I execute  `$ heroku run bundle exec rails webpacker:install`，the situation remains unchanged.
I think the problem is that webpack is not working properly on heroku, but I don’t know how to deal with it.
Please give me some advice, thanks

```
//Procfile
    web111: bin/rails server -p $port
    webpack111: bin/webpack-dev-server



 //package.json  
  {
      "name": "test",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
        "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^3.1.3",
        "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
        "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
        "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
        "@rails/webpacker": "4.3.0",
        "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^9",
        "flatpickr": "^4.6.9",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "postcss": "^7",
        "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
        "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
      },
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "devDependencies": {
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
      }
    }
```

Comment: You're not supposed to start the webpack dev server in your production environment (which Heroku by default is), so remove that line from your Procfile to begin with and see if that helps. If it doesn't, we need the actual logs and not just a single line from it.

Comment: So I should delete webpack123: bin/webpack-dev-server, but the situation still doesn’t improve.

Comment: We need the actual logs.